# YouTube embed request changed only for Safari –> chromeless player inoperable

Tags: safari, youtube, webkit, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a site with an embedded YouTube Flash (AS3) player, and it's no longer working in Safari.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q98x8/), the code for which is merely:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
              data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer">
</object>
```

In Chrome, Firefox, and IE, the request to http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer returns normally (200). In Safari, the server returns a 303 to https://youtube.googleapis.com/apiplayer.

This player loads, but I am unable to interact with it in JavaScript. I assume that's because it's served over https — though I am explicitly requesting http — resulting in a mixed-mode security issue. Here's error I see when trying to do anything with the player (this is with the full chromeless player embed code):

```
>>> player.playVideo()
Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

If I change Safari's user agent to something else, or even just mangle the word "Safari", then the correct player is loaded. I also have no trouble loading the Vimeo and Viddler players (http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf and http://www.viddler.com/player/key).

I see this both in the stable Safari release and in the WebKit nightly. It also occurs with my extensions disabled and in Private Browsing mode.

I tried working around it by embedding `http://youtube.googleapis.com`, hoping that there would be no redirect and I'd get the player over http. But it still redirects to https, and it does so in all browsers.

I filed [this YouTube API ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4887) last week, but there's been no response so far.

Comment: I don't think it's something that will get much attention on the YouTube side ... it's not really a bug, after all, but a design choice (just as you have a specific use case that prevents you from using https or switching to the iFrame API, Youtube has specific reasons for not wanting to deliver the player over an insecure connection). Perhaps you might set up a little local proxy on your end that could receive things over https but then make them available to your app via http?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great point. I think it could be deliberate, but I haven't seen anything to confirm that. And why only Safari? Why is it not documented anywhere? Proxy idea is clever; I think in my case I'd go with one of the other workarounds first, but it probably would work.

Comment: iFrame is the best way I've found to get reliable cross-browser Youtube embeds. What problems would an iFrame approach give you?

Comment: I am running into the same problem, and I need to get the chromeless player working. The iFrame does not cut it for me since I need an absolutely unbranded player, which can only be achieved with the chromeless. iFrame will always display title and play button at the end of the video, regardless of the parameters specified... I tried with a different user agent in Safari, and everything works well. It would be nice to have some insight on this. You can check out an example at: [link](http://clients.brushfiredesign.net/playground/youtube/youtube.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YT API bug report [has been answered](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4887), and there is a workaround: appending the version to the URL:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3">
</object>
```

Apparently when the version is not specified, they fall back to the AS2 player for Safari only. I'm not sure why that would force the switch to https, but regardless, this works.

Comment: is it still the case? I can see yt is using built-in html5 player of safari 9

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's a playback issue with Safari and YouTube. There're multiple solutions suggested at MacRumours http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1098606, like switching to 32 bit browser, use non-HTML5 version, etc.
One that seems to work is below:

> Select Safari > Preference > Privacy > Details
>
> Search for Youtube
>
> Delete the cookie called youtube-nocookie.com then click Done.
>
> Restart Safari and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the suggestions listed there, but unfortunately none worked. I didn't have that cookie set, but clearing all youtube and googleapis data made no difference.